# Django models default error messages into one field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This very simple django restframework code.

models.py

```
class User(models.Model)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('Email','Username','State')
```

views.py

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

If use this I am getting error out put like this

```
{
    "Email": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "Username": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "Country": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
}
```

But I need to change the error out like this.How I can i archive this and any suggestion greatly appreciated.

```
{"error": 
    [
    "Email is required",
    "Username is required",
    "County is required"
    ]

}
```

Comment: What is the objective behind this?

Comment: I am giving my API'S to my frontend developer he request that and he's using  angularjs.

Comment: It might be worth explaining to your front end developer why they are actually separate, they relate to an actual field as they are

Comment: I think it is a better practice to have these field errors separate from non-field errors. So at any point of time if you wish to show what are the errors in `username` field, you can!

Comment: I totally understand what @Sayse , but I've also seen some best practices to write a API'S and I ask some of my friends they are mobile developers they also expect error in single object.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own error messages for any error case:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('Email','Username','State')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.Meta.fields:
            self.fields[field].error_messages['required'] = "%s is required" % field
```

Comment: If I use Media type : application/json it's giving me default error but if i use Media type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded then it's giving me custom error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can always overwrite the create/update methods from the generic views. It would be something like:

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            # TODO: add here your custom error dict using serializer.errors
            return Response({"error":...}, status=...)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Or... you could try to overwrite the serializers... if you don't want to overwrite the view.

(However, there must be a good reason for a JS developer not being able to parse a simple json error object :P)

Hope this helps